# Use of unresolved identifier 'MapTasks' in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am following [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/), as it is pretty old tutorial and they actually used GoogleMaps framework package instead of pods which I followed and everything was going smooth till I reached **Spotting a Custom Location**. In that section they asked to update `func geocodeAddress` as below, and add `var mapTasks = MapTasks()` in ViewController.swift file which I did but it gives me error.

> Use of unresolved identifier 'MapTasks'

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ePSc.png)

```
func geocodeAddress(address: String!, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((status: String, success: Bool) -> Void)) {
    if let lookupAddress = address {
        var geocodeURLString = baseURLGeocode + "address=" + lookupAddress
        geocodeURLString = geocodeURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        let geocodeURL = NSURL(string: geocodeURLString)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            let geocodingResultsData = NSData(contentsOfURL: geocodeURL!)

            var error: NSError?
            let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(geocodingResultsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

            if (error != nil) {
                println(error)
                completionHandler(status: "", success: false)
            }
            else {
                // Get the response status.
                let status = dictionary["status"] as String

                if status == "OK" {
                    let allResults = dictionary["results"] as Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
                    self.lookupAddressResults = allResults[0]

                    // Keep the most important values.
                    self.fetchedFormattedAddress = self.lookupAddressResults["formatted_address"] as String
                    let geometry = self.lookupAddressResults["geometry"] as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                    self.fetchedAddressLongitude = ((geometry["location"] as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lng"] as NSNumber).doubleValue
                    self.fetchedAddressLatitude = ((geometry["location"] as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lat"] as NSNumber).doubleValue

                    completionHandler(status: status, success: true)
                }
                else {
                    completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(status: "No valid address.", success: false)
    }
}
```

Here is my GitHub [repository](https://github.com/shyambhimani/FindMyBuddy.git)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then edit your question with some more detailed and specific information.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my question as per your suggestion. @JamesWood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fully read that tutorial, you will find in the instruction that you need to create a file name MapTasks which is a class.
You can just copy this [file](https://github.com/appcoda/google-maps-api-demo/blob/master/GMapsDemo/MapTasks.swift) from GitHub and add it to your project.

Comment: I have already have MapTasks if you see my GitHub repo you will find it.

Comment: I checked your Github repo. Your class name is MapTask.  But I think it should be MapTasks , with s.

Comment: Oopss that was a silly mistake. btw thank you very much It solved the error.